# insert data into another table using a multi select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using sql server 2012.

I have written a select query below which works fine. However I'm not sure how to insert the data returned from my query into another table (tblTempPrices)?

my insert into

```
;insert into tblTempPrices(DateEntry, DatePrice, ISIN, Price, PriceSource, SecurityType, TableCheck)
```

Query below works

```
with ret as
(
    select distinct ISIN, Price
    from tblFI_Benchmark_R 
    where DateEntry = '2015-10-19'
), 
stat as
(
     select distinct ISIN, Price
     from tblFI_Benchmark_S 
     where DateEntry = '2015-10-19'
), 
allSec as
(
    select * from ret
    union
    select * from stat
)
select '2015-10-20', '2015-10-19', ISIN, Price, 'BARC', 'FixedIncome', 'PCF' from allSec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this -

```
;with ret as
    (
        select distinct ISIN, Price
        from tblFI_Benchmark_R 
        where DateEntry = '2015-10-19'
    ), 
    stat as
    (
         select distinct ISIN, Price
         from tblFI_Benchmark_S 
         where DateEntry = '2015-10-19'
    ), 
    allSec as
    (
        select * from ret
        union
        select * from stat
    )
    insert into tblTempPrices(DateEntry, DatePrice, ISIN, Price, PriceSource, SecurityType, TableCheck)
    select '2015-10-20', '2015-10-19', ISIN, Price, 'BARC', 'FixedIncome', 'PCF' from allSec;
```